# In each case find bases for the row and column spaces of A and determine the rank of A.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

In each case find bases for the row and column spaces of A and determine the rank of A.

$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & -1 & 5 & -2 & 2 \\
2 & -2 & -2 & 5 & 1 \\
0 &0 &  -12 & 9 & -3 \\
-1 & 1 &  7 & -7 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right]
$

My solution:

$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & -1 & 5 & -2 & 2 \\
2 & -2 & -2 & 5 & 1 \\
0 &0 &  -12 & 9 & -3 \\
-1 & 1 &  7 & -7 & 1 \\
\end{array}\right]
$->$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & -1 & 5 & -2 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & -12 & 9 & 1/4 \\
0 &0 &  -12 & 9 & -3 \\
0 & 0 &  12& -9 & 3 \\
\end{array}\right]
$  ->$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & -1 & 5 & -2 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -3/4 & 1/4 \\
0 &0 &  -12 & 9 & -3 \\
0 & 0 &  12& -9 & 3 \\
\end{array}\right]
$ ->$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1 & -1 & 0 & 7/4 & 3/4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -3/4 & 1/4 \\
0 &0 &  1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 &  0& 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right]
$

So i said the rank is 3 because there is 3 rows that are non empty. But how would you find the rest?

Comment: The first, second, and third rows (the rows with the pivots) of the *new* matrix are a basis for the row space. The first, third, and fourth columns (the columns of the pivots) of your *original* matrix are a basis for the column space.

Comment: @Bye_World but there is a pivot in every column in the original, so like 1, -2, -12, -7

Comment: No, you look at your *row reduced* matrix to find the pivots.  But then you go back to your original matrix to find the columns that span the column space.

Comment: @Bye_World so it would be like column 1 would be 1, column 2 is -1, column 3 is 1, column 4 is 7/4, column 5 is 3/4?

Comment: If you've gotten a matrix in [row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form), then the pivots are the first nonzero numbers in each row.  You don't actually have this in row echelon form because you'd need to swap the 2nd and 3rd rows first, but it's close enough to see that the pivots are $1$, $1$, and $-3/4$ (the last row doesn't have a pivot).

Comment: Looks to me like you made an error in your row-reduction. That $1$ in the third row should be in the second instead. The $1/4$ in the second matrix should be $-3$, too, but that looks more like a typo since you carry it along to the next one.

Comment: That is, **assuming you row reduced correctly** (except for stopping one step too soon), *these* are the pivots: $$\require{enclose}\begin{bmatrix} \enclose{circle}{1} & -1 & 0 & 7/4 & 3/4 \\
0 &0 &  \enclose{circle}{1} & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & \enclose{circle}{-3/4} & 1/4 \\
0 & 0 &  0& 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @Bye_World oh thank you